# linux - How to check out how much memory and time used after the program terminated?

Tags: linux

I'm currently working on some OJ system, and the system will give out the TIME and MEMORY usage after my program is run. I know that there is `./time` that could check out time usage, how about memory? Or is there any command that could check both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Peak memory usage of a linux/unix process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `valgrind`.

```
valgrind your_exec
```

When your process exit, `valgrind` will output a summary of bytes allocated/freed during the execution time and how much space was still allocated just before exit

Output example:

```
==840==
==840== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 1)
==840== malloc/free: in use at exit: 88,940 bytes in 163 blocks.
==840== malloc/free: 376 allocs, 213 frees, 208,624 bytes allocated.
```