# How to use dtrace to determine the maximum memory usage of a process

Tags: dtrace

The following dtrace script will give the sum of all allocations a process has performed:

```
pid$target::malloc:entry { @ = sum(arg0); }
```

Now, I'm rather interested in the maximum total allocated memory usage during the life-span of the process (about 50 ms). How can I generate either what would be a graph over time of total allocated memory usage (sum of all mallocs minus sum of all frees), or just its maximum value. I've tried keeping track of all allocated memory blocks manually, but the dtrace associative array size limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your dtrace script will give you an upper bound on the maximum memory utilization since you don't track `free`s as well as `malloc`s. You might not care about this. If you do care, since `free` doesn't take in or return the size of the freed range, you might be better off tracing the `brk()` syscall return value, which also accounts for the size of all metadata that `malloc` stores on the heap. The alternative to this (if you want exact answers) is to figure out how the data structures for `malloc` and `free` work for your OS and dig into some pointer arithmetic in DTrace to get that info.

Second, a word of caution - if you're using this to implement a very fast allocator, keep in mind that you need the size of the *entire* heap (not just the memory that `malloc` returns), since alignment of values stored in memory is important and the ranges returned by malloc don't include this "dead space".

Now, on to your question.

1. You can get a picture over time by tracing the data as it comes in. Just use `printa(@)` to print the current value of the aggregation after every time you call `@ = sum(...)`.
2. Alternately, if you want a more accurate time axis in the picture this would generate, you could record the timestamp with the `malloc` size, like `@[walltimestamp] = sum(...)`. In that case, each entry in the aggregation would only include a single allocation size rather than the sum of all aggregations so far.
3. If you like the first solution better but also want an accurate time axis, just `trace(walltimestamp)` before your call to `printa(@)` in the first example.

If you're not set on using DTrace, you can always use `/usr/bin/time -lp` (on Mac OS X - for other platforms the same thing exists but the arguments are different) to get some static information about process resource utilization.

```
% /usr/bin/time -lp 'date'
Tue Jun 25 14:14:35 PDT 2013
real         0.00
user         0.00
sys          0.00
    561152  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       158  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
     3  involuntary context switches
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am interested in the maximum memory utilization (not just an upper bound, as that is several orders of magnitude too high). I tried tracing `brk()`, but on my OS (OSX) `malloc()` seems to use `mmap()`. I was unsuccessful in getting a reasonable total value out of tracing `mmap()`/`munmap()`. Tracing something like number of currently resident memory pages would be ideal, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: How about running `/usr/bin/time -lp` on your process? I learned this trick [from another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process) and it seems to work pretty nicely on Mac OS X. FYI, there is also the [`vminfo` provider](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/vminfo+Provider) in DTrace, although it would be difficult to use for measuring the maximum size of your process.

Comment: Thank you. `/usr/bin/time -lp` gave me just what I wanted.