# memory usage of a program run under unix

Tags: unix, memory-management

I just wondered if I have already the max RSS value given by time -v, is there any way to get the right RSS value from this command line or as it is wrong, there is no way to find out the right value in KB  or another unit? Any other unix command that could determine the memory usage of a process (program) from the beginning of the process to the end as average or max?

Look forward to your reply,

Carol

Comment: What is your *exact* definition of "RSS value" and "max RSS value" ?

Comment: What program is it? Do you have its source code? Can you improve that source code?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you could consider using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). So for [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) of pid 1234, try `cat /proc/1234/maps` in a terminal (try also `cat /proc/$$/maps` for the current shell, etc...). It shows the current [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

From inside the process, read sequentially the `/proc/self/maps` pseudo-file.

See also `/proc/self/stat`, `/proc/self/statm`, `/proc/self/status` (which you could parse and get the `VmRSS:` line).

You could also use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) & [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html): both commands can be used/configured to show RSS. And also [watch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) with [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) (e.g. `watch ps -l 1234`)

Read also about *process accounting*, e.g. [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html) etc...

You could run your program with `time -v yourprogram its arguments`....

See also [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) & [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html)

Read also [linuxatemyram](http://linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: but if I have a program that takes 2h to run, how can I determine the max or average RAM that it has used without being in front of a terminal when it's running?

Comment: Nitpicking: what is running is a *process*

Comment: Once the process has terminated you usually cannot know how much resources it has used.

Comment: the problem is that the max RSS given by time -v is wrong (see another thread about this in stakoverflow). The problem comes from gnu. otherwise, time -v is perfect as I need such a command to precede my program command line so that the max RAM could be determined during the run time.

Comment: it's much much more that what is used. I try to follow the memory usage with system monitor and compared to what was determined by time and it was totally crapped. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process

Comment: Then sample `/proc/1234/maps` periodically .... But I am not sure that `time -v` is wrong. I believe it is accurate. I trust more `time` than any graphical system monitor.

Comment: No I need program that could determine automatically. But did you read the thread that I sent about gnu time?