# Python3 - Is there a way to iterate row by row over a very large SQlite table without loading the entire table into local memory?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a very large table with 250,000+ rows, many containing a large text block  in one of the columns. Right now it's 2.7GB and expected to grow at least tenfold. I need to perform python specific operations on every row of the table, but only need to access one row at a time.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM big_table') 
table = c.fetchall()
for row in table:
    do_stuff_with_row
```

This worked fine when the table was smaller, but the table is now larger than my available ram and python hangs when I try and run it. Is there a better (more ram efficient) way to iterate row by row over the entire table?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`cursor.fetchall()` fetches all results into a list first.

Instead, you can iterate over the cursor *itself*:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM big_table') 
for row in c:
    # do_stuff_with_row
```

This produces rows as needed, rather than load them all first.

Comment: This method works very well for what I was asking, but restricts me from editing the table while iterating. After performing operations on each row I can no longer update them using c.execute('UPDATE table WHERE  x = y') like I could before. I'm currently using a work around by using a second cursor object to handle the updates. Is this the proper way to do this? Keeping in mind that the operations I'm doing aren't possible in SQL.

Comment: @MarlonDyck yes, you'd use a separate cursor for those updates. That's why database drivers have the concept of cursors :-)

Comment: upvoted! any ideas how you would fill a numpy array with this, i tried append and it works but i am not sure if that is the right/fastest way to do it

Comment: @PirateApp: depends, what is the expected result? A matrix of all rows and columns?  Then use `np.array(c.fetchall())` to pass all rows to the constructor in one step.

Comment: thanks , i tried that but it takes waay too much time on 1 million rows

Comment: @PirateApp: the issue there is that you are loading a million rows into a numpy array from a database. Why are you doing that?

Comment: i am trying to calculate a simple moving average code along with a few other metrics and unfortunately need access to all the data points :(

Comment: @PirateApp: Isn't that something the *database* could do for you?

Comment: The database could some of the simpler ones like sma but exponential moving average, exponential weighted moving average and many others are far more complicated metrics to do in the database, given their nature they require a full sequential scan

Comment: @PirateApp a SQL database can still do those, using windowing and CTEs (`OVER(...)` and `WITH ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a minimal runnable example that tests [what was mentioned by Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582757/895245), create a database with 10m points:

```
f="10m.sqlite"
rm -f "$f"
sqlite3 "$f" 'create table t(x integer)'
time sqlite3 "$f" 'insert into t select value as x from generate_series(1,10000000)'
```

Use this program to loop over the database:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("10m.sqlite")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from t')
x = 0
for (i,) in cur.fetchAll():
    x += i % 2
print(x)
```

Get the maximum memory usage with [Peak memory usage of a linux/unix process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process)

```
command time -v ./main.py |& grep 'Maximum resident'
```

gives:

```
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 873600
```

so about 900 MB, wow. Naively we'd expect at most about 80 MB given 8 bytes per int. And then if we instead do:

```
for (i,) in cur:
```

it has only 11 MB:

```
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 11256
```

Tested on Python 3.11.4, Ubuntu 23.04.