# Is there a way to measure how much a shell command used memory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to measure how much an executed terminal command/operation used memory, like the built-in command `time` for measuring execution time. I'd like to compare commands with different parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/774601/524743

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was looking for something like [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html).

This is how I used it:

```
$/usr/bin/time -f "%E %M" *<command>*
```

That gave me:
time (%E) - elapsed real time (in [hours:]minutes:seconds);
**memory (%M) - maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in kB.**

Comment: Note that the full path `/usr/bin/time` is required when you run in Bash

Answer (score 3):

With top or htop you can view memory usage for all processes, not only for one.