# MemoryError with numpy where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I'm getting a `MemoryError` with `numpy.where` but I'm not sure why. I can't post the actual code here, but below is a small working example that replicates the issue.

```
import numpy as np
dat = np.random.randn(100000, 1, 1, 1, 45, 2, 3)
# The following two steps seem superfluous but I wanted to replicate
# behaviour in the original code    
cond = dat[:,0,0,0,0,0,0] > 0
cond = cond[:,None,None,None,None,None,None]

dat2 = np.where(cond, dat, 0)
dat[...,2] = np.where(cond, dat[...,2], dat2[...,2]) # Causes MemoryError
```

I understand that adding more memory to my computer will solve the issue, but I would like to understand what is going on here.

I expect the array slices above will not copy the array but only return a view, but I suppose that it is actually copying the array for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "magic" going on here, your data array that you create using `np.random.randn(100000, 1, 1, 1, 45, 2, 3)` is very large.

Numpy seems to store each number as 64 bit (8 byte) float, so your array takes up around 206 Megabytes of memory (100000 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 45 * 2 * 3 * 8).

[`/usr/bin/time -v python test.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774601/489345) says that the program uses around 580 MB at its peak, which might be due to copying the object.