# Does 'maximum resident set size' equal 'required RAM size for the process at least'?

Tags: memory

Can I say 'maximum resident set size of a process' equals 'required RAM size at least for the process'?

Am I right? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of sorts, yes. However, the OS may over allocate memory to the process,
or under allocate (and therefore, use swap space). At any rate, it is a good approximation.

See [Peak memory usage of a linux/unix process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process)