# Unit of maximum resident set size in the output of time

Tags: macos, memory-management, command-line

Can someone let me know what is the unit of maximum resident size in the output below?

```
/usr/bin/time -l mvn clean package -T 7 -DskipTests
...
real       530.51
user       837.49
sys         64.28
3671834624  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
   2113909  page reclaims
     26733  page faults
         0  swaps
      5647  block input operations
     26980  block output operations
        15  messages sent
        25  messages received
       687  signals received
    406533  voluntary context switches
   1319461  involuntary context switches
```

I am trying to measure peak memory usage of a process as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890083/785523).

Environment - Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.5 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit of `Maximum Resident Size` is bytes.

Comment: did you find any way to make it human readable?