# Linux command that tracks statistics of CPU usage while running application on HPC/HTC

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing, pbs

In my PBS script, I am running matlab and would like to know how many many cores were actually used during the time.  Especially I would like to know the max number of cores used at a time.

If I only allocate x number of cores but at any time matlab uses more than x number of cores then my job will be stopped and cancelled by the HPC/HTC system.

Ideally the command and output would be as simple as

```
cpustats matlab -nojvm -r "someExperiment(params);exit()"

Max CPU usage: 12.5 cores
Average CPU usage: 6 cores
Min CPU usage: 0.5 cores
```

I can't monitor the progress manually because it is a batch script so I am planning on running once with plenty of cores and then modifying the rest so I don't have to wait so long.

I have searched and searched for a command like this but the following don't seem to be what I am looking for

- `top` finds the current cpu usage which I don't have access to
- `ps` finds cpu allotted to a process and not actual usage
- `watch` might be useful to query random cpu times and output them but would like a continuous stream if possible
- `time` is really close to what I want but doesn't keep track of peak CPU usage

The most similar question I could find was [this one about peak memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774556/peak-memory-usage-of-a-linux-unix-process)