# How to find the maximum memory that my Python code needs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-management

I need to add some lines to my code that shows the maximum memory that has been used in the runtime of the code. My code opens a CSV file and processes it and write a new CSV file. I need to know the maximum memory that has been allocated throughout the time of running.

I need this to compare different alternatives in terms of memory usage. I have tried `memory_usage()` and `df.memory_usage(deep=True).max()` but I don't know what is the numbers they generate.

I need to know that for example: this code to process this CSV file has allocated  (for example) 12 MB of RAM in the **most-memory-consuming-moment of runtime.**

Comment: If you're on a UNIX-like system, this is basically a duplicate of [Peak memory usage of a linux/unix process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/774556/364696).