# How to measure/throttle curl memory use?

Tags: curl, memory, memory-management

When the `curl` executable redirects its output to stdout, is its memory-use proportional to the total size of the downloaded content?

If I'm downloading a 1GB tgz with `curl` that I pipe to `tar` -- as in the example below -- is the memory used proportional to that 1GB?

```
curl -sSl https://path/to/1GB_file.tar.gz | tar -xvxf - -C /
```

If the answer is 'yes', it there a way to "throttle" or limit the maximum memory used by `curl` without outright causing the download itself to fail?

Is there a way to measure how much memory `curl` uses -- either dynamically, or a maximum value -- while downloading a given file?

Comment: I very much doubt it’s related - both cURL and tar will stream. I would imagine memory use is just the buffers. Dumping it to your stdout though might be an issue - as your terminal might buffer the whole lot. In terms of measurement, maybe just use `top` in another window in the first instance?

Comment: How about [`time -v`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/774601/2071828)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - don't seem to have `time` on my linux box, and I'm not allowed to `apt install` anything. >:(

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer this as an answer, but it's cobbled this together from new reading/discovery, so this is likely not ideal.

After spawning my `curl` process, I quickly determine its `pid` while the process it still running, and in another shell I run `grep VmPeak /proc/<pid>/status`. Do that a couple times, and hopefully close to when the `curl` process ends, so you're getting a truly comprehensive peak value.

For a 1.7GB file, `curl` seems to use a peak of 223016 kB.

I *think* this means `curl` doesn't strictly use memory proportional to the target file size (i.e. >= the target file size)